# How to use a bottom concave ebelskiver (Æbleskiver) pan on a glass cook-top stove?

Tags: cast-iron, pancakes, electric-stoves

I've recently come in to a lovely cast iron ebelskiver pan (pictured below) and would like to try to make some  ebelskivers.

[image: ebelskiver pan with concave bottom]

The problem is I don't have a gas range and I'm rather sure that my glass-top stove won't be able to adequately or evenly heat the pan due to its concave underbelly. The bottom of the wells aren't even level with the skirting rim of the pan.
Is there anything I can do short of replacing my range top or starting a fire in my backyard to use this pan to make some stuffed pancakes?

Comment: is it an inductive or resistive stovetop?  I've used a cast iron aebleskiver pan on an inductive top, although mine has some [extra material underneath each well, similar to this one](http://www.solvangrestaurant.com/shop/sci-cast-iron-aebleskiver-pan/)

Comment: As it turns out I've purchased a gas range top since posting this question and no longer need an answer, however someone else may in the future. I'm leaving it unanswered for the moment as I have no way to verify any of the supplied techniques.

Answer (score 6):

You could consider heating it up, while empty, in an oven (I would go for, say, 200C/390F). Keep it there for at least 30 minutes: the transfer of heat from the air to the cast iron is not very efficient! Then take it out quickly, pour the batter in, and return it to the oven until done (and then make the next batch, if you're making multiple).

An issue with this could be that the Æbleskiver might cook too quickly from the top. You might need to experiment with the target temperature you leave the oven at.

Comment: I thought of this, though it may be by best option, unfortunately it really isn't ideal given that Æbleskiver need to be manipulated throughout preparation.

Answer (score 5):

We have been making them for years; the past 15 have been on the flat glass top. Just heat the pans on the stove before you start cooking. It will likely take a few tries before you find the right temperature setting for your range. We hear ours to a 4 out of 10.

Answer (score 4):

I have used this same pan for years on my glass cook top. However, to keep the heat even I would put a small grate under it and that worked perfectly. This year I have a new induction cook top and Aebleskivers did not do well. Induction will not recognize this pan because it is not flat. I bought the adapter for regular pans to be used on induction and that worked partially. Had to put temp high and it would eventually shut off that burner so moved to another one. Had to constantly do it and Aebleskivers did not brown well. Have been making them on Christmas Eve for 47 years and grew up with a Mom doing them for us always on Christmas Eve. Have to search now for a pan that will work on induction or but the electric one.

Comment: Well that bites. Can you set the pan inside another with water?

Comment: Mary, that sucks ... see my comment on the question, as I can confirm that style of pan works on an induction burner.  (maybe it won't cook *exactly* like what you're used to, but I was able to get good Æbelskiver out of them)

Answer (score 2):

This might be tricky.

Do you have a grill? Placing the pan on hot coals might work - not an ideal solution though.

Comment: I've got an enclosed gas grill. The burner sadly is the wrong shape and too deep in to be safe to cook over it.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just buy a single gas or butane burner to use for your Aebleskiver pan?  They also work well for tableside dishes such as Crepe Suzette, Steak Diane, ad infinitum (depending on the style you choose).  You can use them outdoors too - at home or away.